# How do I need to write the 3rd line - Not enough information to infer type variable T

Tags: kotlin, generics

I'm new to Kotlin and try to convert a project from Java to Kotlin
I just need one last step and I don't understand what's going on :(

I'm getting a `Not enough information to infer type variable T` on `model.predict` call

```kotlin
override fun link(word: String): LinkSuggestion {
    val input: DoubleArray = gramToInt.toArray(word)
    val output: Array<Any> = model.predict(input)
                                // ~~~~~~~ Not enough information to infer type variable T
    val maxPredictionIndex: Int = (output[output.size - 1] as Long).toInt()
    val maxPredictionProbability: Double = output[maxPredictionIndex] as Double
    return LinkSuggestion(word, intToLink.fromInt(maxPredictionIndex), maxPredictionProbability)
}
```

where `model` is `import org.pmml4s.model.Model`

---

The previous Java code:

```java
@Override
public LinkSuggestion link(String word) {
    double[] input = gramToInt.toArray(word);
    Object[] output = model.predict(input);
    int maxPredictionIndex = ((Long) output[output.length - 1]).intValue();
    double maxPredictionProbability = (Double) output[maxPredictionIndex];
    return new LinkSuggestion(word, intToLink.fromInt(maxPredictionIndex), maxPredictionProbability);
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the method signature of `model.predict()` or add a link to its source?

Comment: @ST-DDT I think it's this one https://github.com/autodeployai/pmml4s/blob/80fc2dc0f83c6b457244a3ba34fbacc93b139598/src/main/scala/org/pmml4s/model/Model.scala#L201-L214

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to write

```kotlin
val output: Array<Any> = model.predict<Any>(input)
```